# Rails Authentication via Web Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

So, this may be a kind of dumb question, but I checked the Google and got no hits.  We want to host multiple Rails apps in a way that makes them look homogeneous.  We want all the apps to have the same look and feel, and all the apps to use the same sign-on database.

Theming I think we could accomplish by just putting the site theme into a gem, and requiring that gem from our github repository in each app.  However, auth is trickier.

I know that I can achieve this "for free" by just not making the different portions of the site (store, chat forums, etc.) different apps.  If they're all, say, Rails Engines, we can basically drop them into the same application with their own namespaced routes, and have a single plugin that does auth.

However, for various reasons we'd like to keep these separate apps, if that's technically possible. The number one reason is scalability; since this will be a hosted site, we want the flexibility to spin up more instances of, say, the store (perhaps to handle a holiday sale rush), without needing to spin up the chat forums.  Also, we want to be able to completely isolate the portions of the code that AREN'T intertwined.

Ideally, the databases would be separate too (keeping us from falling back into the rut of "put everything including the kitchen sink in the db"), but I do know that one "cheap" way to do cross-app auth is just to use the same plugin (say, Devise), and just point to the same DB.

So, I'm thinking that maybe the way to do this is to auth via a web service call.  Is this prior art -- does anyone have a gem for this that "just works" so that authentication can be shared across all apps?  Or am I just entering into a world of pain by trying to build things this way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a single sign on approach described at:

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

The single sign on approach with oauth and devise has some drawbacks. The main problem I had was I was unable to extend the timeout time across multiple apps.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this.  It appears like a good idea, but the code is still pretty raw; certainly not at a "push button and go" state for something as important as security.  We're rethinking our app architecture to determine if multiple apps is really the right way to go.